# Rails 3: SMTP Settings for Google Apps / Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, smtp, heroku, actionmailer

Here are my smtp settings for Google Apps in setup_mail.rb.

```
  :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",  
  :port                 => 587,                 
  :domain               => 'mysite.co',  
  :user_name            => 'noreply@mysite.co',      
  :password             => 'password',      
  :authentication       => 'plain',             
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
```

My development logs show in detail the e-mails being generated and sent to the right e-mail address... but they are not arriving. I can only think that there must be something wrong with the settings above. Can you see what the problem is?

Once this is solved, would I have any issue getting it to work on Heroku?

---

Note: the above is logging a deprecation warning:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Giving a hash to body is deprecated, please use instance va
riables instead. (called from process at C:/Sanj/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gem
s/actionmailer-3.0.0/lib/action_mailer/old_api.rb:77)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out that the issue was elsewhere - an old AuthLogic tutorial had put me in the right direction on sending out activation codes but the wrong direction on sending out the e-mails themselves. Rails was generating the e-mail but not sending it because the mail_helper's code wasn't going the final step.

If you're reading this in retrospect, what I learned: make sure your Rails 3.0 user_mailer has (or similar):

```
mail(:to => "#{user.login} <#{user.email}>", :subject => "Registered" )
```

Answer (score 5):

I think if you are using rails 3, the correct approach to setup mail would be to follow this [railscasts tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/206-action-mailer-in-rails-3) on action mailer.

Answer (score 5):

in your user controller don't forget to add the **.deliver**

```
UserMailer.registration_confirmation(@user).deliver
```

that is what stumped me

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used rails3 but I remember [reading](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/206-action-mailer-in-rails-3) that sent emails in development are sent to the sender. Your deprecation warning is because you're defining variables for the email template in the previous hash format. Rails 3 works [differently](http://lindsaar.net/2010/1/26/new-actionmailer-api-in-rails-3). In my experience deploying to heroku works flawlessly but you will need to define [mx records](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=33915).

Comment: Hi Mark. Can you please be more specific? How do you actually fix the deprecation? Sent e-mails are only redirected to the sender in the development environment if you specify an interceptor.

Comment: Also, I have updated my MX records to Google Apps. I have a number of new e-mails under my domain name that work properly when I send/reply to e-mails manually - the question is now how do I get Rails to send these e-mails too :)